# Trouble with 'double precision' in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I've got a problem with coordinates field while importing data from csv. Have you any ideas how to resolve it?

```
    ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "1e-005.0
```

Comment: I *think* you'll need to alter the input file. PostgreSQL will accept values like "1e5", but not like "1e-005.0".

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't accept 1e5 for quote enclosed csv, which are I'm afraid the most common.

Comment: It is `.0` at the end what is causing problem. There are many correct variants, unfortunately it's not `1e-005.0`. E.g. the following works: `1e-005, 1.e-005, 1.0e-005`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually edit coordinates that someway got expressed in normalized scientific notation and turn them back to their decimal form, up to 15 digits in your case.